# Unable to view logs of a running application

Tags: 16.10, ubuntu-studio, logs

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu 16.10. I am running an application like Kazam.  I would like to see the the log files of Kazam when it runs.  There is no Log file viewer.  I also saw the kern.log, syslog, and auth.log but there is hardly any logs specific for an application that I run.  So how do I see logs for a running application like Kazam even if it has no crashes?

Answer (score 3):

Not all applications produce a log. However, you can obtain some output from the [kazam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kazam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) process by adding the `--debug` switch and launching it via the terminal.

Source:

https://github.com/aaae/kazam